# Дискретная математика. Работа с битовыми операциями с Си

Tags: c, дискретная-математика

У меня задача заключается вот в чем: есть элементарная конъюнкция записанная вот в таком виде 11**. Мне надо расписать все возможные наборы которые может принимать эта конъюнкция. Т.е. 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111. Помогите пожалуйста, не могу додуматься как это реализовать на С!

Comment: Что такое "записанная вот в таком виде"? Звёздочки всегда вместе и справа? Остальные - всегда единицы? Почему это названо "конъюнкцией"?

Answer (score 0):

Подскажу как додуматься.

Переберите все двоичные числа от нуля до `(2 в степени n) - 1`, где `n` - количество звездочек.